# Did de Gaulle Machiavellianly "cultivate" the Algerian junta but condemned it after taking power in 1958?

Tags: history, france

The New Yorker [writes](https://www.newyorker.com/magazine/2018/08/20/how-charles-de-gaulle-rescued-france) about the 1958 events in France:

> Then, in June of 1958, a group of right-wing French military men, alarmed by the Fourth Republic’s failure to defeat the ongoing rebellion in Algeria, and worried that the French nationals there would be abandoned, set about to organize a coup of sorts. They more or less took charge in Algiers, and demanded a change of government in Paris. De Gaulle, who with rather magnificent Machiavellianism both did and did not encourage the junta’s actions, cultivating its actors at the time and condemning them not long after, was asked by the French President to lead a government of “national union” for six months and then to offer a new Constitution, which became that of the still extant Fifth Republic.

Details on  de Gaulle [allegedly] "cultivating" the Algerian junta seem completely absent from his Wikipedia bio. So what level of evidence is there that he "cultivated" the junta?

Comment: “Cultivating its actors” and “magnificient Machiavellianism” are not objective categorizations, but [“Je vous ai compris”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_de_Gaulle#Algeria) alone could possibly qualify.

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil': wikipeida isn't terribly clear. “Je vous ai compris” seems to be from from June '58. https://books.google.com/books?id=rfpZCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA119